# flutter with add svg to a specific part

Tags: image, flutter, svg

I currently have a page with an image like this, but I want to add an svg image to the button section at the bottom as in the second image. How can I do it?

İmages

[image]

[image]

My Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'URL Shortener',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
    );
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Shortly",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40,
                      height: 2.0,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/illustration.svg',
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Let's get started!",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 60,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        "Paste your first link into the field to shorten it",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 74, 85, 10),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 40,
                  child: TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            const Radius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Shorten a link here ...'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("Button Click");
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blue,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      minimumSize: Size(60, 40),
                    ),
                    child: Text('SHORTEN IT!'),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Hello, I currently have a page with an image like this, but I want to add an svg image to the button section at the bottom as in the second image. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use stack in this case, or clipper from Container. Replace `ListView` with `Stack `

Comment: Where should I add the svg in this case? @YeasinSheikh

Comment: On last child  of ListView use `SizedBox < height:x <Column< two buttons here>>>` and `Column >mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo Widget**

```
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Shortly",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                  height: 2.0,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          // SvgPicture.asset(
          //   'assets/illustration.svg',
          // ),

          Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(.3),
            child: Text("SVG assets here"),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Let's get started!",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 60,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    "Paste your first link into the field to shorten it",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 74, 85, 10),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          SizedBox(
            /// bottombackground height
            height: 220,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                /// background svg asset
                Container(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(.4),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 40,
                      child: TextField(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 0,
                                style: BorderStyle.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: 'Shorten a link here ...'),
                      ),
                    ),

                    /// a little space between buttons
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("Button Click");
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          minimumSize: Size(60, 40),
                        ),
                        child: Text('SHORTEN IT!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `SizedBox(height:x)` to provide spaces between widgets. Does it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/a.svg",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween ,
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Shortly",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 40,
                              height: 2.0,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:200.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Let's get started!",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 60,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                  "Paste your first link into the field to shorten it",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 74, 85, 10),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 150.0,
                      color: Colors.purple,

                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 300,
                              height: 40,
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                        const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                      ),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 0,
                                        style: BorderStyle.none,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    filled: true,
                                    hintText: 'Shorten a link here ...'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 300,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  print("Button Click");
                                },
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.blue,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                                  minimumSize: Size(60, 40),
                                ),
                                child: Text('SHORTEN IT!'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.